# Python OSError No space left on device

Tags: python, linux, ext4

Im writing a lot of files to a folder, no subdirectories, however after 2.8 million files this error shows up:

```
with open(bottleneck_path, 'w') as save_file:
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/home/user/path/redacted'
```

I've checked the length of the filename which is only 149 characters long. The file size is supposed to be around 18K.

My operating system is Linux.

df -i:

```
Filesystem                               Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                                    4106923     544  4106379    1% /dev
tmpfs                                   4113022     836  4112186    1% /run
/dev/sda2                              28401664 9008557 19393107   32% /
tmpfs                                   4113022      40  4112982    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                   4113022       5  4113017    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                   4113022      16  4113006    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                                     0       0        0     - /boot/efi
```

df -T

```
Filesystem                             Type      1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev                                   devtmpfs   16427692          0   16427692   0% /dev
tmpfs                                  tmpfs       3290420      22136    3268284   1% /run
/dev/sda2                              ext4      447088512  355325584   69029056  84% /
tmpfs                                  tmpfs      16452088      82448   16369640   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                  tmpfs          5120          4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                  tmpfs      16452088          0   16452088   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                              vfat         523248       3684     519564   1% /boot/efi
```

du -sh .

```
56G
```

ls | wc -l

```
2892084
```

From my understanding ext4 should be able to handle this just fine.

EDIT:

tune2fs -l /dev/sda2

```
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          cd620466-1f88-400b-acf5-457a9c9544cf
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              28401664
Block count:              113587456
Reserved block count:     5679372
Free blocks:              82864623
Free inodes:              25755495
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      996
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Wed Mar  1 15:14:22 2017
Last mount time:          Mon Mar 27 13:20:00 2017
Last write time:          Mon Mar 27 13:20:00 2017
Mount count:              35
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Wed Mar  1 15:14:22 2017
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          1813 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       1312056
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      e186507d-32b5-49c0-8ce1-09bf2a75d816
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Using

```
touch /home/user/path/redacted/somefile_1
```

throws an error but the same filename structure with a different name works fine. eg:

```
touch /home/user/path/redacted/somefile_2
```

Comment: Are you writing all 2.8 million files as children of said directory, or is there nesting as well? It seems that ext4 has a limit of 64k subdirectories per directory, according to [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/506465/is-there-a-hard-limit-to-the-number-of-files-a-directory-can-have)

Comment: @HoriaComan there's no nesting, look at that ls.

Comment: ext4 should well be able to handle this. There are no subdirectories.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Its posted. Above the df -T

Comment: @Wesley: uh sorry, for some reason I didn't notice.

Comment: Sure, it may be able to handle it but it's still a fairly bad idea that's trivially avoidable.

Comment: @pvg Yup, missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to hash collision. Disabling dir_index resolved the issue.

Comment: Without dir_index, aren't there any issues with performance? Are file lookups still acceptably fast?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default limit on the maximum inodes for ext4, it depends on the size of the device and the options chosen at creation. Check the existing limits using

```
tune2fs -l /path/to/device
```